# Checking whether we have access to multiple Biqquery tables with different datasets using Service account

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

1. Read the ingestion request file from Excel which contain mutliple tables, datasets and project id.
2. Use the service account credentials to check authority in BigQuery.
3. .Need to check did service account has access to bigquery table to run query
4. Update the ingestion request file whether we have access to the table or not and output to the same Excel file.

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
# Path to the service account key file
service_account_key_file = 'path_to_your_service_account_key_file.json'

# Path to the ingestion request Excel file
excel_file_path = 'path_to_your_ingestion_request_file.xlsx'

# Path to the output Excel file
output_file_path = 'path_to_your_output_file.xlsx'

# Authenticate using the service account key file
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_key_file)
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials)

# Read the ingestion request file
ingestion_requests = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)

# Function to check authority for a table
def check_authority(client, project, dataset, table):
    try:
        # Construct table reference
        table_ref = client.dataset(dataset, project=project).table(table)
        # Get the IAM policy for the table
        policy = client.get_iam_policy(table_ref)
        # Check if the service account email is in the list of members with appropriate roles
        for binding in policy.bindings:
            if (binding.role == "roles/bigquery.dataViewer" or
                    binding.role == "roles/bigquery.user") and credentials.service_account_email in binding.members:
                return "Access Granted"
        return "Access Denied"
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

# Perform the necessary checks and create a report
report = []
for index, row in ingestion_requests.iterrows():
    result = check_authority(client, row["Project ID"], row["Dataset"], row["Table"])
    report.append({
        "Project ID": row["Project ID"],
        "Dataset": row["Dataset"],
        "Table": row["Table"],
        "Result": result
    })

# Create a DataFrame from the report
report_df = pd.DataFrame(report)

# Save the report to the output Excel file
report_df.to_excel(output_file_path, index=False)


Tables exists in BQ but still getting output as false or getting ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid JWT Signature.'}) error
```

Comment: Do you want to know if the service account as specific permissions on Google Cloud?

Comment: I want to check whether Service account has access to table to run queries.

Comment: Why don't you use policy analyser for that? https://cloud.google.com/policy-intelligence/docs/policy-analyzer-overview